# Datastore limitation in Ancestor relation

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using Java. I have simple scenario here. There are Four kinds 1-user, 2-post, 3-comment, 4-like

Ancestor relation is used like this.

```
 user---->post---->comment
           -
           ------->Like
```

User is parent of post and grand parent of comment and likes. Post is parent of comment and like.

In my app mostly I need posts with recent 3 comments. And when user click on comment button then get all comments of that post and same for likes. Something like Facebook and Instagram. I think for this situation above structure(relation) is useful, isn't it ?

But problem is that **As described in documentations maximum operation rate of 1/s. If you increase from this operation there may be an Error.**

> There is a write throughput limit of about one transaction per second within a single entity group. This limitation exists because Cloud Datastore performs masterless, synchronous replication of each entity group over a wide geographic area to provide high reliability and fault tolerance. [Documention](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/entities)
>
> Avoid writing to an entity group more than once per second. Writing at a sustained rate above that limit makes eventually consistent reads more eventual, leads to time outs for strongly consistent reads, and results in slower overall performance of your application. A batch or transactional write to an entity group counts as only a single write against this limit.  [Documention](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices)

There is a quite possible there is more than one like or comment in one sec. So what I do in this case.

Any suggestion how can I overcome this situation or any other better structure ?

Comment: Can you give the share the link where " As described in documentations maximum operation rate of 1/s. If you increase from this operation there may be an Error." is given?

Comment: I read in many places But I mention two of them check the update